# how to resolve multiple post back issue due to multiple jQuery files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, postback

I have included two jquery files on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My problem is, due to multiple Jquery files on a page, the postback event is firing two times.

Can anyone help me out on this? How we can fix it?

Comment: @SpaceBison That's UI and jQuery..

Comment: Including jQuery and jQueryUI on the same page will not cause the problem you describe. Please post your code making the AJAX request.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Ahh - eyesight fails me yet again.

Comment: Have you tried to re-install your firebug ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not calling form.submit() in the onSubmit action of a form.  This is the most common double postback issue I have seen.  See below.

example:

```
<form id="foo" onSumbit="dofoo">
<input type="submit" name="do">
</form>

<script>
  dofoo(){

  jquery('foo').submit()
  exit true; 
  }
</script>
```